# CouchDB / MongoDB for syncing distributed MySQL application

Tags: mysql, mongodb, couchdb

I have an online application which is based on MySQL but I have also deployed this application to different customers and will continue to do so. Now I want these local DBs at my customers' sites to be synced with the one in my server every time there is change. I know I can go with MySQL replication but it's tough considering I have to do it in every customer's site. So I was wondering does CouchDB or MongoDB make this issue any easier than the normal MySQL replication? Is there a way to use both and make this process less painful?

Comment: What is the workflow you want to achieve? Do you want to setup replication from a master instance to each customer instance?

Comment: Also will you have access to and ownership of the customer site instances? Without access it may be hard to operate and administer any replicated database scheme.

Comment: @TheDude what I'm looking for is replication from the different customer instance to the master instance only.

Comment: @JamesWahlin yes I have access and complete ownership of the customer's site instances.

Comment: You state replication is "from the different customer instance to the master instance" in your comment above. Does this mean writes on the customer instances that propagate to the master? I agree with @TheDude that having a more complete picture of your workflow would help in making a recommendation.

Comment: Yes I hav writes that must be propagated to the server